# Importing .csv values as single list in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a `csv` file that has one column of records that looks like this:

```
test1
test2
test3
...
```

I imported them into a Python list using this:

```
import csv

results = []
with open('test.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(row)

print(results)
```

That worked fine, however, it prints them out like this:

```
[['test1'],['test2'],['test3']]
```

How would I adjust my code to have them print out in a single list instead like this:

```
['test1','test2','test3']
```

and, is one output more preferred than the other? I realize it is use-case dependent.  I am just curious how others work with imported lists via .csv, and what advantage one would have over the other.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have csv... you just have... text...

Comment: that's true.  maybe in this specific example a .txt file would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following code

```
import csv

results = []
with open('test.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(row[0])

print(results)
```

Comment: this works well. And if your csv has multiple columns, but you only want to use one of the columns as a list, just change the index number in `(row[0])`.